# 240 V-only Dryers, Ovens, Ranges, and Cooktops in North America?

Tags: kitchens, garage, dryer, appliances, oven

Gas-powered clothes dryers, ovens, cooktops, and ranges use 120 volts for their control panel. As a result, manufacturers have opted to save money on their high-powered all-electric heating appliances, which require 240 V for the heating elements, by keeping the same 120 V control components. This means they use both 120 V and 240 V simultaneously, and is why electrical clothes dryers, baking ovens, cooktops, and ranges need the 3rd leg (pre-1996) or the 4th leg (for circuits installed since the 1996 NEC), which is the neutral. I could not find any information online regarding 240 V kitchen and laundry appliances in the United States and Canada that do not also use 120 V. Of course, internationally, such as in the Philippines and South Korea, which use only 240 V but at 60 Hz, I have seen people on online forums saying that the government has mandated that new appliances be 240 V-only (either by integrating a small transformer inside or using 240-volt individual parts) because having the user install an external step-down transformer is too much of a hassle.

In my case, I want to install 240 V receptacles in the garage to enable supplying high-powered portable equipment such as power tools and portable Level 2 EVSEs. Since I have to go through the hassle of installing the brand-new circuits anyway, I want to make them as flexible as possible. Power tools such as compressors and welders only use 240 V, so they do not need a neutral. Same with Level 2 EVSEs. I want to be able to take my EVSE whenever I travel beyond the metropolitan area, especially when I visit an RV park, so I will not consider installing a fixed wall charger. Like in most houses built since the late 1970s, the laundry appliances are currently located within the laundry room in the air-conditioned part of the house. However, it is most likely that I will not need to use all 3 bays of my garage for parking, even in the long run, so I might want to move the laundry equipment to the unused garage bay to make more open space for the habitable part of the house. Washers use only 120 V at under 15 A, so they are not a problem at all. However, all-electric washers require 240 V for the heating elements. Additionally, I may want to place another cooking range in the garage for the one time per month I cook pungent foods to avoid stinking up the habitable part of the house.

I do not want to install the neutral conductor because it is a waste of money and material when they are not needed. So, are there any all-electric full-size clothes dryers, baking ovens, cooktops, and ranges available on the market in the United States (specifically California) that use 240 volts only when I want to use them in the garage perhaps 5 years later? I generally do not mind the warranty, so I would be open to using used (which are out of warranty anyway) commercial electric appliances too. Of course, I can always import one from the Philippines or South Korea, but the shipping costs would be astronomical and there would be no warranty from using the product out of their intended territory, and it would be cheaper to just install the neutral conductor.

Comment: Once a week rather than once a month. If it were only once a month, I'd simply use the outdoor grill and unscrew the countertop range and move it to the garage for a day.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, a "shopping question". If this is really what you want, contact manufacturers and/or retailers and ask...

Comment: Unfortunately, I already asked the appliance guy at Home Depot today, and s/he just said electric dryers and ovens only use 240 volts because they only have 1 plug rather than 2 plugs. I immediately left because of their ignorance of the neutral leg on the plug.

Comment: if you import something and it burns down your house, don't expect insurance to cover your loss. How much cost are you really saving by not running the center tap?

Comment: @dandavis This is no different from using a laptop that was purchased in another country that does not meet the requirements to be sold in US (can't think of any examples, but just an illustration) that catches fire in the US and burns the house down. Also, I specifically stated that I will NOT import one anyway because it will cost more.

Comment: In the context of owning a house with a three-car garage, purchasing multiple EVs and building a second kitchen for use just once a year, your focus on saving maybe $150 on a piece of wire while backing yourself into a corner is extremely hard to understand.

Comment: This is entirely irrational. If you want to economize on wire, consider running one big aluminum feeder from your main panel to a sub-panel in the garage and then make branch circuits locally as needed. 2-2-2-4 Al is half the price of 6/3 copper.

Comment: "However, all-electric washers require 240 V for the heating elements" <- Not true. Are you referring to all-electric **Dryers**?

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest nope. laptops use power bricks, not mains inputs. The brick can be universal (100-250v ac), or you can easily replace it to provide the laptop DC in a UL/code friendly manner.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, I am aware of that. I meant if the power brick was rated to accept 120 V but was not UL listed (or any other NRTL) and it causes the laptop and/or itself to catch fire.

Answer (score 9):

> I want to make [the new circuits] as flexible as possible.

is in direct contradiction with

> I do not want to install the neutral conductor because it is a waste of money and material when they are not needed.

You cannot have both. If you want a 240V circuit to be flexible then include that neutral.

So either save that bit of money now or deal with that headache of the missing neutral in 5 years while you are cursing your past self.

Comment: I implied as flexible as possible only for loads that do not require the neutral. If I wanted to supply loads that use both 120 and 240 V simultaneously, then of course I would install the neutral conductor and not be asking this question in the first place.

Comment: My argument remains the same, a lot of 240V loads also require a neutral (for better or worse) So to make a 240 circuit "flexible" you need that neutral.

Answer (score 3):

Dryers indeed use 120V for parts commonality.  To beat that problem, look for *heat pump* dryers which run the whole machine on 240V. They are often co-marketed in Europe, so you can see the advantage.

Cooktops do not use neutral. You'll have no trouble finding a no-neutral cooktop.

Ovens do not use 120V for controls. They do not seek parts commonality with gas ovens. They want 120V for the **oven light** - so that consumers can use a "common" incandescent light. They've never heard of CFLs or LEDs, clearly :)  A great many ovens will work fine if denied neutral - check the schematic.  The oven light will not work.  You could also hack the oven to use a 240V oven light.  Even if the oven has 120V controls, neutral could be synthesized onboard the appliance by a tiny transformer, since the control load is typically only a few watts.

A "Range" is an American term for combination cooktop and oven. Lowest common denominator, obviously!

> Since I have to go through the hassle of installing the brand-new circuits anyway, I want to make them as flexible as possible.

I gather you don't want to spend a lot of money on costly long cables. **Don't**.  Run a single run of dirt-cheap *feeder* to a sub panel right in the garage.  Now, the individual circuit runs are quite short and you won't worry about the cost of ten feet of neutral wire.  And certainly, use aluminum on large circuits and feeders where it is proven reliable. This isn't 1973, the alloys are better and we know how to use them correctly.

2-2-2-4 SER or MH feeder is our "go to" for a sub panel feeder. 90A and costs less than 8/2 copper.

> I want to be able to take my EVSE whenever I travel beyond the metropolitan area, especially when I visit an RV park, so I will not consider installing a fixed wall charger.

The state of EV charging is changing fast, and will continue to do so. Several of your understandings are already obsolete. Even I have trouble keeping up, honestly.

RV parks only have one type of (EV-usable) receptacle - the NEMA 14-50.  Most **travel unit EVSEs** come with two plugs - normal 120V plug, and the 14-50.  That's because the travel unit is for travel!  **So how will you plug this into your no-neutral house?**  You are depending on your auto manufacturer to offer a dongle for NEMA 6-20, 6-30 or 6-50.  If they don't, you'll be obliged to install a NEMA 14-50 **and run neutral**.  Can't do a 14-50 without neutral, or rather, it would be extremely foolhardy and could get you sued when somebody fries their RV.

The travel EVSE has one job: Travel. It needs to live in your trunk for opportunity charging on the road (even though, DC fast chargers are proliferating so widely that they really aren't necessary anymore).

Think about *another* wall-mount EVSE for daily charging. Why? #1 because it's a drag to have to stow the travel unit *every single time* and it invites damage. #2 if you're going to plug/unplug everyday, you need an industrial grade socket ($$$$$).  #3, wall units can do things travel units cannot - such as power sharing, solar diversion or panel overload limiting, which saves you the trouble of a Load Calculation and/or service upgrade.

But again, the tech is moving very fast, so don't get mind-locked into particular plans that will be wrong when you get the EV.

Comment: quote: They want 120V for the oven light - so that consumers can use a "common" incandescent light.
This is incredibly stupid. They should just use a special 240 V incandescent light if high temperature is a limitation.

quote: neutral could be synthesized onboard the appliance by a tiny transformer
Of course, I have considered this.

quote:
So how will you plug this into your no-neutral house?
Plug adapters exist, even for international travel. The fact that people cut off the ground prong baffles me.

Comment: quote: You are depending on your auto manufacturer to offer a dongle for NEMA 6-20, 6-30 or 6-50.
False. I can buy an aftermarket one (as long as it's not a knockoff one) and it doesn't have be produced specifically for the same vehicle model and generation.

quote: The travel EVSE has one job: Travel. It needs to live in your trunk for opportunity charging on the road (even though, DC fast chargers are proliferating so widely that they really aren't necessary anymore). Yes, not really necessary, but still handy if I happen to be camping at an RV campground once every 5 years or so.

Comment: quote: #1 because it's a drag to have to stow the travel unit every single time and it invites damage. #2 if you're going to plug/unplug everyday, you need an industrial grade socket. Nope, the EVSE will be left on a table. It is totally safe because the power pins in fact are not even energized until the vehicle communicates to it via the low-voltage data pins that it is safe to charge, which is why wall "chargers" do not need to be disconnected from the house circuit.

Comment: quote: You are depending on your auto manufacturer to offer a dongle for NEMA 6-20, 6-30 or 6-50. Obviously, I'm not an Apple fanboy who will only buy Apple products and spend extravagant amounts of money on them only because it is that brand.

Comment: quote: I gather you don't want to spend a lot of money on costly long cables. answer: Nope, it has nothing to do with mechanical flexibility. I meant functional flexibility, and did not intend for "flexibility" to have ambiguity in this context. If I used "versatility", then there would not be any ambiguity.

Comment: Note that CFLs and LEDs generally wouldn't survive in the oven environment. You can cook an LED with a 25 watt soldering iron if you're sloppy,

Comment: You really will be better off with a wall mounted charger; faster charging, among other reasons. And you _can_ take it with you when you move, with no more hassle than installing it in the first place. I tend to agree that you are optimizing the wrong things here and are likely to regret this approach, but I'm not going to waste energy arguing about it; you've been given the reasons, and if you still disagree at least you aren't planning anything actively unsafe.

Comment: @CoastCityLapse00crashtest if you're just going to argue with very sensible answers, what are you doing here?

Comment: @CoastCity I completely agree 120V oven lights are absolutely stupid in the modern timeframe... you may have picked up on my snark about that. Or maybe not, because your head seems *very, very full* of your own strongly held opinions, and seems like there's not much room for anything new :) Just remember an opinion is not a fact.

Comment: @CoastCity I was presuming you were using the travel EVSE that comes with the car, because it's FREE :) I didn't imagine you'd run out and buy an Apple one. But damn, you could do worse - Tesla's is the cheapest EVSE in town, and it also has more features than most. And it comes in J1772 now.  **It is very important not to use adapters to step down a travel EVSE's socket to a lower ampacity circuit** due to the way current limiting works with EVSEs.

Comment: My dilemma has been totally solved! Thank you so much for the recommendation on heat pumps and letting me know that cooktops do not use neutral. I do not need an oven outside of the kitchen anyway. Better yet, lowered-powered full-size cooktops only need 20A instead of range 40A. However, only NEMA 14-30, 14-50, 10-30, and 10-50 appliance cords are available. NEMA 10-series has been outlawed since the adoption of the 1996 NEC due to lack of grounding conductor. So, I can just install a NEMA 14-30 cord and then plug into the NEMA 6-30 wall receptacle via a plug adapter. Same with 24A EVSE.

Comment: Since the NEC is only for installations of the building electrical system, and I am not fastening anything in place, they are not fixtures. So, I am not installing any appliances to the building, I am only installing the branch circuit and receptacles. So, the use of plug adapters is fully code compliant.

Comment: From the appliance manufacturer's side, they only mention that I need to use a specific cord for the installation and connect to a circuit with a specific voltage and sufficient ampere rating. I am in compliance with their installation instructions because I installed a cord that is specifically approved by them for the appliance and am connecting to a circuit with the correct voltage and a high enough ampere rating, so I won't miss out on warranties as a result.

Comment: Especially that I will only use UL (or CSA/ETL or other NRTL) listed plug adapters for safety, quality, and durability, which saves money over the long run compared to cheap knockoffs which last only a year before failing.

Comment: Also, even if the NEC also applied to portable things that were plugged into the premises wiring, the NEC's statements of overstepped authority (such as 625.44(A)) only states that listed equipment be connected to receptacles in general and certain types of equipment be connected to the premises wiring via specific plugs. Since the premises wiring ends at the receptacle outlet, the listed plug adapter still makes the portable equipment connected to the premises wiring through the specified type of plug. As a result, listed plug adapters are fully allowed as long as they provide grounding, etc.

Comment: Also, even if the NEC also applied to portable things that were plugged in, the NEC's statements of overstepped authority (eg. 625.44(A)) only states that listed equipment be connected to receptacles in general and certain types of equipment be connected to the premises wiring via specific receptacle outlet types. Since the premises wiring ends there, there is no ambiguity that the listed plug adapter still makes the portable equipment connected to the premises wiring through the specified type of plug. As a result, listed plug adapters are fully allowed as long as they provide grounding, etc.